# Vim is not loading Vagrantfile ftplugin

Tags: vim, vagrant

I realize this is a recurring question, but none of the other responses on StackOverflow or Google seem to work, so I'm asking separately. I'm trying to get Vagrantfiles to show up with Ruby formatting, but having little success.

In ~/.vim/ftplugin/vagrant.vim, I have the following:

```
augroup vagrant
    au!
    au BufRead,BufNewFile Vagrantfile set filetype=ruby
augroup END
```

My .vimrc is pretty simple:

```
set shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4
filetype on
filetype plugin on
syntax on
```

When opening an .rb file, formatting is as expected (using whatever default Ruby formatting vim came with -- I didn't add any additional ftplugins other than the one for Vagrantfile).

Upon opening a Vagrantfile, there's no formatting.

Running `:set ft?` returns `filetype=`.

Running `:filetype` returns `filetype detection:ON  plugin:ON  indent:OFF`.

I'm somewhat at a loss here, so any help is appreciated. Running vim 7.3 on Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~/.vim/ftplugin` is not used by filetype detection.

Try write in `~/.vim/filetype.vim`.